# Change style for "input[type=text]" back to style "input"?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to change the style for "input[type=text]" back to the style that was set for "input" through jQuery?

https://jsfiddle.net/L9fjL7vu/7/

This does not work:

```
$( "input[type=text]" ).css('background-color', $( "input" ).css('background-color'));
```

Comment: Can you explain your requirement some more? Because if we know your end result then that could be done in a better way.

Comment: I have already stated my requirement.... I need all styles for "input[type=text]" to be the same as the styles set for "input".

Comment: See, both selectors are same in your case. If we see in terms of specificity the first one with attribute selector wins. So still if you want to do the same then you should add unique identity to those elements.

Comment: Unfortunately adding unique identifies is not possible.So my only solution would be to set the styles for "input[type=text]" back manually to what they were within the stylesheet for "input"

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting the background colour is because you have multiple `input` fields. So it wouldn't be able to differ between which background colour you wanted with `$("input")`. Unless you was to grab the input field which has no `ID`, `class` or `type`.

You would have to have a `ID` or `class` on the default input field.

Check my example:

```js
$("input").val($( "input" ).css('background-color'));
$("input[type=text]").css("background-color", $(".test").css('background-color'));
```

```css
.test {background-color:red}
input[type=text] {color:blue; background-color: pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"></input>
<input class="test"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris... but I am unable to change any of the input fields to include ID or class. I was hoping it was possible to revert back to the initial style set for "input" within the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below. Use `:not([type])` to select which has no type. Hope it helps.

```
$( "input" ).val($( "input" ).css('background-color'));
$( "input[type=text]" ).css('background-color', $("input:not([type])").css('backgroundColor'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Azim... this would work in the situation where I do have an INPUT tag without a type. But unfortunately I do need to make this work when I do not have an INPUT tag without a type. I was hoping it was possible to revert back to the initial style set for "input" within the stylesheet?

Comment: Then use different `css class` for changing style. @Merlin

Comment: Unfortunately Azim I am unable to add or change any INPUT tags. I think my best option is to just manually set the styles of "input[type=text" to what ever they were for "input" myself.